# Writing in .csv file and getting next cell

Tags: c++, file, csv

I've found that you need to use `,` to seperate cells you want to write in, but it somehow doesn't work for me.
Here is code:

```
    fileName "example_1.csv"

    void World::saveDataToFile(std::string fileName){
    std::ofstream myfile(fileName);


    if (myfile.is_open())
    {

        for (int index = 0; index < dataList.size(); index++){

            myfile << dataList[index].ants << "," << dataList[index].beetles << "," << dataList[index].empty << "\n";
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else std::cout << "Unable to open file";
}
```

It just writes in same cell using commas. I can't find any other solution.

How can I get next cell?

***EDITED***

Wrong spreadsheet:

[image: excel spreadsheet]

```
//    std::vector< std::vector <Organism* > > world; // wrong vector
      std::vector<Data > dataList; // this is the right one!
struct Data{
    Data(int a, int b, int e) : ants(a), beetles(b), empty(e){}
    int ants;
    int beetles;
    int empty;
};
```

Involved functions:

```
void World::saveData(){
    dataList.push_back(Data(countOrganismType(ANT),countOrganismType(BEETLE),countOrganismType(NONE)));
}
int World::countOrganismType(Organism* org){
    int count = 0;  
    for (int x = 0; x < wSizeX; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < wSizeY; y++){
            if (compare(world[x][y], org)){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, did you increase width of the cells ?

Comment: when I open the file everything is in A1, A2, etc.. But there weird thing is when I close it, program asks me to confirm changes, but I haven't done any.

Comment: Your logic seems sound.  I wonder if the problem is in your class and/or in how you're filling the vector.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything wrong with your code. Are you sure the import parameters in you spreadsheet software are ok ? Sometimes we don't notice that we have marked the newline as a column separator.

Comment: Im using `dataList.push_back()`, decleared `vector< vector< Data > > dataList` and `struct Data { int ants; int beetles; int empty; };`

Comment: Your vector declaration is 2 dimensional but your use seems to be 1 dimensional

Comment: sorry wrong vector :) Will edit

Comment: It appears to me your spreadsheet is expecting quotes and a comma to find the columns.

Comment: something like this "\",\""? What do you mean?

Comment: something like this: "1","2","3"

Comment: Tried this: `myfile << "\"" << dataList[index].ants << "\"" << "," << "\"" << dataList[index].beetles << "\"" << "," << "\"" << dataList[index].empty << "\"" <<  "\n";` but it takes quotes off only from first one and doesn't separate anything.

Comment: Check the settings in your spreadsheet software.